# Populating UIViewController with data from different sources

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, instantiation

I have an UIViewController and a UITableView inside it. I have views in my app mockups that look identically, they just have different text in a single label and different contents of UITableView, so I want to use the same ViewController twice.

My idea is to set a property (`next`) that will specify from where I need to get a data and then instantiate this view like this:

```
MyViewController* next = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyViewController"];
next.which = 1;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:next animated:true];
```

And then inside `MyViewController* next` populate view with the content depending on the value of `which`. Is there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an appropriate approach.  You make a subclass of UIViewController that captures the shared behavior between your different views but that allows customization of the content (based on `which`, as you described).  You then instantiate your subclass as needed.